# Thread-safe LRU Cache Implementation in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, cache

I am trying to implement a **thread-safe** LRU cache algorithm, please review my code and would really appreciate some criticism or suggestion.

Some assumptions:

1. capacity will be larger than 0

Some questions I have:

1. I know it is better to encapsulate variables in a class and declare them private, but since DDLNode is simply a data class, is it acceptable to make the variables public ?
2. I am considering to extract the following block of code (inside `put`) into a function (something like `addEntry(key, value`)

   ```
   DDLNode<K, V> node = new DDLNode<>(key, value);
   addNode(node);
   entries.put(key, node);
   ```

   do you think it's neccesary? or the original code is self-explanatory enough?

Here is the code, Thanks in advance!!

````
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

interface CacheAlgorithm<K, V> {
    
    public V get(K key);

    public void put(K key, V value);
}

class DDLNode<K, V> {
    
    public V value;
    public K key;
    public DDLNode<K, V> prev;
    public DDLNode<K, V> next;

    public DDLNode() {}

    public DDLNode(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class LRU<K, V> implements CacheAlgorithm<K, V> {
    
    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    private final int capacity;
    private final Map<K, DDLNode<K, V>> entries;
    private final DDLNode<K, V> head;
    private final DDLNode<K, V> tail;

    public LRU(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        head = new DDLNode<>();
        tail = new DDLNode<>();
        entries = new HashMap<>(capacity);
        head.next = tail;
        tail.prev = head;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(K key) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (!entries.containsKey(key)) {
                return null;
            }
            DDLNode<K, V> node = entries.get(key);
            moveToMostRecent(node);
            return node.value;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (entries.containsKey(key)) {
                DDLNode<K, V> node = entries.get(key);
                node.value = value;
                moveToMostRecent(node);
            } else {
                if (entries.size() == capacity) {
                    removeLeastRecentEntry();
                }
                DDLNode<K, V> node = new DDLNode<>(key, value);
                addNode(node);
                entries.put(key, node);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void removeLeastRecentEntry() {
        entries.remove(tail.prev.key);
        removeNode(tail.prev);
    }

    private void moveToMostRecent(DDLNode<K, V> node) {
        removeNode(node);
        addNode(node);
    }

    private void removeNode(DDLNode<K, V> node) {
        DDLNode<K, V> prev = node.prev;
        DDLNode<K, V> next = node.next;
        prev.next = next;
        next.prev = prev;
    }

    private void addNode(DDLNode<K, V> node) {
        DDLNode<K, V> headNext = head.next;
        head.next = node;
        node.prev = head;
        headNext.prev = node;
        node.next = headNext;
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 2):

I like the codestyle!

**Code organization tips**:

- Its better to move `DDLNode` into `LRU` and make it static, because sole purpose of this class is to be used by `LRU` class.
- If you are not going to expose `DDLNode` to outside world, then it make sense to make it also `private`. Keeping its fields as public is fine here.
- If you want to expose `DDLNode` to outside world (for example, in iterator), you should think more thoroughly about field access. You can get inspiration from `HashMap.Node` class, for example: fields here have default access, so `HashMap` itself can manipulate them without using getter or setters. Also note, that there is no `setKey()` method for outside world, because if we change the key on the node it will break the map.
- Maybe you just put all the classes into 1 file to make it easies for us to read , but if not - its bad practice to have more than 1 class/interface in 1 file.

**Optimization tips**:

- In `get()` you are doing unnecessary `.containsKey()` call, because just `.get(key)` is enough: if key if present, it will find it; if not, then it will return null and you can then just return from method.
- Unnecessary `containsKey()` call in `put()` as well: you can just check `.get(key) == null` instead.
- head and tail will always occupy memory, event if map is empty. They could be removed, although then you should be more careful will null checks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! Appreciated it.Some followup to your comment:                                  
1. The DDLNode class is actually gonna be used if other classes ( I actually have another cache algo class MRU), how can the HashMap.Node design be applied in that case? 2.if DDLNode is used by mutlipled classes, you think i can still keep the fields public? (I do know it's an anti-pattern but also think using setter and getter function everywhere is quite messy :p, need a second opinion) Thanks.

Comment: @yploo First of all, what this DDLNode? Abbreviations, especially not widely known, are confusing. My guess is that its DoublyLinkedListNode (which is DLLNode - even more confusing name). 
Anyways, if you are going to implement Most recently used cache - you can just use this class for both - the only difference will be in `removeLeast/MostRecentEntry()` method. In this case keeping `Node` class as private static makes total sense.

My example about HashMap.Node was to show that if you want to expose those nodes, you should be careful what getters/setters you expose